# ranger file explorer — how to change the font (ie, to this linked example)

Tags: x11, theme, ranger

**My question: how do I change the font in Ranger?**

The custom colorscheme files I have downloaded don’t seem to ‘include’ their font (ie, see [this one](http://dotshare.it/public/images/uploads/583.png) from this [theme](http://dotshare.it/dots/583/))?

- I suspect it may involve changing my X fonts using .Xresources ?

  - If so, I’d rather not mess with that because it’s a pain to tweak, such as having to restart X all the time to see the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is determined by the terminal you are using.

The font must be installed on your system, then for xterm or urxvt edit `~/.Xresources`:

```
UXTerm*faceName: xft:Consolas:pixelsize=32:antialias=true:hinting=true

URxvt*font: xft:Consolas:pixelsize=32:antialias=true:hinting=true,xft:Symbola
```

Other terminals (like Alacritty) use config files.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I didn’t know a lot of that, so it was very helpful. Best regards.